# How to bind data of firebase with angularJS scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi how can i bind data that i received from firebase with scope in angularJS.
I am new to this and following though [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_scopes.asp). So i am not sure what i am missing. 
I am using

```
"angular": "^1.7.2",
"angular-route": "^1.7.2",
"firebase": "^5.2.0",
```

And my code is like this

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/',{
    templateUrl:'home.html',
    controller:'UserController'
  })
})
app.controller("UserController",  function ($scope, $routeParams, $location) {
    firebaseRef.child('users').on("value", function(response) {
      $scope.userCount=response.numChildren();
  });
})
```

And in html i am doing like this

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="my-first-app">
............<HEADER AND TITLE  AND BODY>......
    <h3>User count : {{userCount}} </h3>
</body>
</html>
```

But nothing is coming even though if I `console.log` the value of `response.numChildren()` I see `4`.

Can anyone please tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the complete user html view?

Comment: @MarcusHöglund, yes i added the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time your Firebase `on("value"` callback is invoked, AngualarJS is not expecting changes to the HTML anymore. So you have to explicitly tell it that you're changing the HTML, by using `$apply()` or `$timeout()`:

```
app.controller("UserController",  function ($scope, $routeParams, $location) {
    firebaseRef.child('users').on("value", function(response) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.userCount=response.numChildren();
      });
  });
}
```

Also see:

- [Firebase data normalized. How should I fetch a collection based on this structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721460/firebase-data-normalized-how-should-i-fetch-a-collection-based-on-this-structur/21733457#21733457)
- [Firebase callbacks and AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065367/firebase-callbacks-and-angularjs/13083437#13083437)
- [AngularJS & Firebase '$timeout is not defined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526153/angularjs-firebase-timeout-is-not-defined/35526213#35526213)

Comment: Thank you :)) that worked.
Seems like something synch and asynchronous behavior of typescript

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ng-view to the view.

Try it like this

```js
var app = angular.module("my-first-app",["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
  .when('/',{
    template:'<h3>User count : {{userCount}} </h3>',
    controller:'UserController'
  })
})
app.controller("UserController",  function ($scope, $routeParams, $location) {
    $scope.userCount = 3;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="my-first-app">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes i have added that,, but still the value is not coming.

Comment: @user7747472 updated my answer with an example of how to route the html correctly